# Enforcing DLL Dependencies

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll, coupling

#### Background

My solution consists of two projects:

1. A standard Windows application
2. A DLL which my application *does not* use directly, but instead injects it into a target process

Basically, from my application's perspective, the only requirement that the DLL must meet is to be present in the working directory of my application. In short, my DLL doesn't export any functions that are of interest to my application.

---

#### Question

I would like to strongly couple these two binaries. What are my options aside from manually calling `LoadLibrary` in my application?

If this is too vague, please let me know.

---

#### Edit

Since no one seems to be "answering", I ended up doing what `EFraim` suggested (see comments).

I exported a dummy function from my DLL and added the DLL's generated `*.lib` file as an additional dependency in my application's linker property sheet. Now, at run-time, if the DLL's missing, Windows gives a nice error message and terminates execution. As an added bonus, the DLL image is also locked after successful IAT initialization; this prevents things like user deletion.

Comment: Are you trying to couple the build projects at compile time, or the binaries themselves at run time?

Comment: I'm trying to couple them at run-time. That is, I'd like my application to fail (not silently, if possible) if my DLL is not present in the application's working directory. Is this sort of thing done manually (i.e., via LoadLibrary, etc.), or automatically set somewhere in my application's property sheets?

Comment: To follow up, what happens if I create a dummy export that my application will consume via its IAT and my DLL happens to be missing? Is this behavior predictable? Will Windows terminate my application's execution?

Comment: If it is not delay loaded, then yes, the application won't even start executing.

Comment: EFraim, thanks. Should have replied via an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't expect releasing dll and exe separately, you can add dll into your resourses and unpack it from there on startup.